# Looking for Floodplain Modelling instructions

Tags: qgis

I'm really new to GIS, yet I have a project that I am doing that is GIS entensive.

I want to do a flood plain (for a river whose shapefile i have) and publish whatever output (its a map i presume) on a website for guys to access and consume. Can someone help me with an easy to follow floodplain-modelling instructions?
I would love to follow the tips and learn more.

Comment: What kind of GIS software do you have access to, or prefer to use?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://grass.osgeo.org/uploads/images/Gallery/raster/trento_flooding1966.jpg?

Comment: Indeed that kind of output is what I hope to achieve... it looks superb to me...

Comment: And again, I have read that its possible to produce that kind of output in a 3d fly through (video) model, you have experienced that somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean exactly by "floodplain modelling"? Do you want the area that will be under water given a water level of X in the river?

A primer, albeit from 2002, will be http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc02/pap0490/p0490.htm .

Comment: Yes, what i mean is the area that will be under water when the river is upto level say X as you put it. Also if you have an idea, you can suggest to me what kind of data i will require to input to get this kind of output.Thanks for the suggestion, i will go through it and glean whatever i can from it.

Comment: Input is the river network and a Digital Elevation Model. For DEM it depends on what resolution your result has to have, where in the world your study area is and how much you are willing to pay.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup... What i am doing is fairly simple class project, nothing of commercial value to me, yet it interests me alot to be able to venture into something new, every so often. My study is is Kenya, more specifically I am interested in Western kenya and Nyanza province because of the perennial flooding in these areas. I cannot pay anything (yet) coz its more like an assignment to me, as we speak. if it was a funded project i woul recruit and pay professionals to help me out.... One day I hope i will re embark on the project with a wider scope. Thanks a lot til_b

Comment: I would then look for the SRMT DEM data for Kenya, using http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp .

Comment: Thanks til_b , you have been very helpful. In fact your assistance has opened a whole world to my eyes (GIS-wise speaking), let me see what i can fumble around and do with this data. I didn't even know it existed! Thanks again, and have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

A paper describing the modelling of flash floods using Grass GIS:

http://www.nio.org/nio/uploadnews/277_2_second_floods.pdf

Comment: Thanks nickves. the document is quite detailed, I hope to walk through it and see what it entails. You have an idea of a powerpoint kinda thing on the same?.....

Comment: No, unfortunately :( But if someone knows anything about it I would also be interested to take a look at it. ;)

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway for your time... someday someone is gonna crack it open. thanks.